# RSpec not get value from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to create a test with rspec and capybara. When I run test, the app don't get value from db. I have this in layout

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse
    %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      %li.dropdown
        %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"} Home
        %ul.dropdown-menu
          %li= link_to "#{menutr.old}", plans_path(template:1)
```

And error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `old' for nil:NilClass
```

But before I run seed in development db and after that I copy this db to test. In development/production mode everything works great.

Comment: What is supposed to be `menutr` ?, it is not defined anywhere, and it is not an instance_variable

Comment: It's temporary translation text in DB.